# Razor Class Library - Is there a way to compile all Pages/ as Pages/<module name>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-class-library

How can you automatically move all RCL pages to a sub-folder of `Pages/`, such as `Pages/<module name>` at compile-time, or at WebApplication import-time?

I need this to be transparent such that, in the RCL solution, all pages are in `Pages/`, but compiled, they are in `Pages/<module name>`. Or, they're compiled at `Pages/`, but when imported  by the WebApplication, they are hosted in `Pages/<module name>`.

Is there a project level setting which can prepend the compiled pages with some folder name? Or some other mechanism I can use to achieve the same effect?

**Attempted Solutions**

I thought about adding routing options to the RCL pages themselves via the `@page` razor directive but decided against it because it would have to be done to each page individually, and I need something more general which will apply to all pages in a RCL.

I looked up ways to import the RCL content under a different folder via Startup.cs's `ConfigureServices()` and `Configure()` but to no success with Conventions. Both [`PageRouteModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.pageroutemodel?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and [`PageApplicationModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.pageapplicationmodel?view=aspnetcore-2.1) conventions only see the overwritten pages. Also tried to use `ConfigureFilter` but it ran into the same issue.

Tried to look at adding something in the RCL's root `_ViewImports.cshtml` to apply some sort of directory offset, but I wasn't able to find good documentation on the razor directives I can use here.